# 3 columns. Prevent last column from wraping and start all its elements from the new row

Tags: html, css

its responsive page. When resizing the social buttons div is wrapping.
How to prevent it, and instead make it start from the new row at the bottom in one line? Thank you.

white-space:nowrap  doesn`t work

```css
.main-footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: #364B66;
}

.main-footer .footer-text {
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-footer .footer-text ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding-right: 10%;
}

.main-footer .footer-text ul li a {
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

#social {
  margin-right: 0%;
}

.fa {
  color: gray;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 2px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class='main-footer'>
  <div class='container-fluid'>

    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'>
        <div class='footer-text'>
          <h1>name</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'>
        <div class='footer-text'>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#!">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Aviso legal</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Seguridad</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Privacidad</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Politica de cookies</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'>
        <div class='footer-text'>
          <div id='social'>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-google"></a>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

When resizing the social buttons div is wrapping.
How to prevent it, and instead make it start from the new row at the bottom in one line? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

nav a {
  margin-right: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="#">Aviso Legal</a>
  <a href="#">Seguridad Privacidad</a>
  <a href="#">Politica de cookies</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi, that doesn`t resolve my problem with the last column. I wonder how to prevent social buttons from wraping when the browser is about 75% and make all buttons go down in one line (just like it happens when the screen is smal). Thank you.